# HKAnchoredObjectQuery deleted objects is empty in iOS 9.0 but works fine with iOS 9.2.1. Is this a update in iOS 9.2?

Tags: ios, ios9, healthkit, ios9.2

HealthKit's HKAnchoredObjectQuery is not returning deleted objects in iOS 9.0. Even if i delete a object and then add a object the deleted objects array is always empty (except on the first launch of app).

But the same code works fine with iOS 9.2.1. The deleted objects are returned whenever a object is added to health app and observer query is fired.

Is this some new update in iOS 9.2.1 and the bug with deleted objects is resolved in this version?

I could not find any Apple documentation confirming this.

Edit:
The code firing the query is

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [HKQuery predicateForSamplesWithStartDate: [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-172800.0]                                                                endDate:nil                                                                 options:0];

 HKAnchoredObjectQuery *query =
    [[HKAnchoredObjectQuery alloc]
     initWithType:sampleType
     predicate:predicate
     anchor:anchor
     limit:HKObjectQueryNoLimit
     resultsHandler:^(HKAnchoredObjectQuery * _Nonnull query,
                      NSArray<__kindof HKSample *> * _Nullable sampleObjects,
                      NSArray<HKDeletedObject *> * _Nullable deletedObjects,
                      HKQueryAnchor * _Nullable newAnchor,
                      NSError * _Nullable error) {
}];
```

Comment: Please post the code that is using the anchored object query. What predicate are you using?

Comment: Please check the edit

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug was a bug in iOS 9.0 that was fixed in 9.1. You can work around the issue by not specifying a predicate that constrains on the `startDate` or `endDate` of `HKSample`.